# Add a single fragment to a screen multiple times

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment, google-now

I am new to android and I am working on a project that displays cards (like on Google Now but all cards are the same size). My question is, is it possible to add the same fragment (a general design for the card) multiple times to the same screen and have them be position after each other in a row or column? If so how would I go about that?

Comment: Does it have to be fragment? From what I understand using recyclerView should be enough for you or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Create a template fragment (eg. TempFragment extends Fragment). Then initilise a new TempFragment each time you need with the data you want to display and use a FragmentManager to add it to the view you want. As for the row or column layout you can use TableLayout in your main layout. Your question is very vague and I'm afraid I can only help you this far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your Adapter's item to implement your fragment. Google's Api Demos has this kinds of example( Support4Demo).

Answer (score -1):

You can use RecyclerView with its Adapter class. Google uses same subject for displaying a similar layout items.

https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

you can see here ... there is all you need.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.